# Looping through lists to create a cartesian product by row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, product, cartesian

I'd like to expand my rows by their cross product across multiple lists. The current logic I use is:

```
list = [['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'], ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe']]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(list, names = ["column1", "column2"])
    pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
```

which unfortunately will not work for more than one list. How would I be able to run the cartesian product of something that looks like this: 
[[['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'], ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe']],[['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'], ['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe']]]
and still have them only run for two columns. I'm looking to produce a crossproduct of 18 (2 * (3 ^ 2)).

Comment: Can you update the question with the expected output that you are looking for?

Comment: expected output would be useful

Comment: Expected output, and making it so that every list isn't identical will greatly help people understand where the 18 products should come from. Perhaps you're looking for `[[*itertools.product(*x)] for x in lst]`

Comment: They main point of interest is that I have a two lists nested within one list. How would I be able to run the code I included above over each list individually, and append them at the end?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide both sample input and output, because the way your question is worded is unclear as to what you actually need to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) allows you to create a cartesian product from an arbitrary number of iterables:

```
itertools.product(*lst)
```

Comment: IIUC, `itertools.product` and `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` pretty much give the same thing.